# Total the nth number in a colon delimited file and put result into bash script variable

Tags: bash, awk

I have a file of many lines.  In each line, numbers are separated by a colon `:`.

I want to add up the nth number in each line and put this total value into a bash script variable.

I think this can be done with a single script line based on `awk` but so far I am frustrated by the syntax.

AND there is a header of Y lines in the file.

How can I do this?

EDIT: Now I got it figured out

```
foo="$(awk -F : '/regex that matches $Y/ { next } { a+=$1 } END { print a }' sofar1.txt)"
echo "foo is :'$foo'"
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ foo="$(awk -F : '/regex that matches Y/ { next } { a+=$3 } END { print a }' <<< $'1:2:3:4\n2:3:5:6')"
$ echo "$foo"
8
```

Comment: `NF > Y` would be better, wouldn't it?

Comment: @muru: Sure, if it's a fixed number of lines.